# Flink can't access leader jobmanager and failed to start job

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-flink

Our Flink cluster has two jobmanagers. Recently the job often goes down whenever jobmanager leader switches, and flink can't recovery the previous job after the switch. Also the job can not automatically start when I restart the flink cluster. So I have to manually start the job. According to the log, it seems whenever a new jobmanager leader is elected, connection to the new leader is refused, and this leads to the failure to start the job that. On our jobmanager server I can't find an active port 58088 open. I wonder if the talk between flink and zookeeper has some problem. We are using flink-1.0.3. 
What can be the possible reason for this? Is it a flink bug? Thanks.

---

Log:

```
2017-03-09 15:32:41,211 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService  - Starting ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService.
2017-03-09 15:32:41,243 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.JobManagerRetriever       - New leader reachable under akka.tcp://flink@172.27.163.235:58088/user/jobmanager:36e428ba-0af3-4e39-90d4-106b7779f94a.
2017-03-09 15:32:41,318 WARN  Remoting                                                      - Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://flink@172.27.163.235:58088]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: /172.27.163.235:58088
2017-03-09 15:32:41,325 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.JobManagerRetriever       - Failed to retrieve leader gateway and port.
akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://flink@172.27.163.235:58088/), Path(/user/jobmanager)]
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:65)
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:74)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:267)
    at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:508)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:541)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:531)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:87)
    at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.postStop(Endpoint.scala:561)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPostStop(Actor.scala:475)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundPostStop(Endpoint.scala:415)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:210)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:279)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
2017-03-09 15:32:48,029 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - JobManager akka.tcp://flink@172.27.163.227:36876/user/jobmanager was granted leadership with leader session ID Some(ff50dc37-048e-4d95-93f5-df788c06725c).
2017-03-09 15:32:48,037 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Delaying recovery of all jobs by 10000 milliseconds.
2017-03-09 15:32:48,038 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.JobManagerRetriever       - New leader reachable under akka.tcp://flink@172.27.163.227:36876/user/jobmanager:ff50dc37-048e-4d95-93f5-df788c06725c.
2017-03-09 15:32:49,038 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at app87 (akka.tcp://flink@172.27.165.66:32781/user/taskmanager) as e3a9364cd8deeebf8a757d3979c5ae55. Current number of registered hosts is 1. Current number of alive task slots is 4.
2017-03-09 15:32:49,044 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at app83 (akka.tcp://flink@172.27.165.58:40972/user/taskmanager) as 0c980a4c64189d975aa71cb97b1ecb7c. Current number of registered hosts is 2. Current number of alive task slots is 8.
2017-03-09 15:32:49,427 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at app27 (akka.tcp://flink@172.27.164.5:50762/user/taskmanager) as 7dcc90275bd63cbcda8361bfe00cb6e8. Current number of registered hosts is 3. Current number of alive task slots is 12.
2017-03-09 15:32:49,676 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at app26 (akka.tcp://flink@172.27.163.245:41734/user/taskmanager) as ab62098118261dcaa2d218ea17aa8117. Current number of registered hosts is 4. Current number of alive task slots is 16.
2017-03-09 15:32:49,916 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at app84 (akka.tcp://flink@172.27.165.60:53871/user/taskmanager) as 012f186f437e7ba95111ff61d206dae6. Current number of registered hosts is 5. Current number of alive task slots is 20.
2017-03-09 15:32:49,930 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at app85 (akka.tcp://flink@172.27.165.62:50068/user/taskmanager) as 68506e37647dfbff11ae193f20a7b624. Current number of registered hosts is 6. Current number of alive task slots is 24.
2017-03-09 15:32:50,658 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at app86 (akka.tcp://flink@172.27.165.64:57339/user/taskmanager) as c1e922599fae53e6edc78a2add4edb61. Current number of registered hosts is 7. Current number of alive task slots is 28.
2017-03-09 15:32:50,780 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at app25 (akka.tcp://flink@172.27.163.241:45878/user/taskmanager) as 3ee2f5d3cb8003df5531d444bd11890c. Current number of registered hosts is 8. Current number of alive task slots is 32.
2017-03-09 15:32:58,054 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Attempting to recover all jobs.
2017-03-09 15:32:58,083 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Fatal error: Failed to recover jobs.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /apps/flink/recovery/submittedJobGraphb6357063f81b (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalDataInputStream.<init>(LocalDataInputStream.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.open(LocalFileSystem.java:143)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FileSerializableStateHandle.getState(FileSerializableStateHandle.java:51)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FileSerializableStateHandle.getState(FileSerializableStateHandle.java:35)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.ZooKeeperSubmittedJobGraphStore.recoverJobGraphs(ZooKeeperSubmittedJobGraphStore.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:433)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(JobManager.scala:429)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(JobManager.scala:429)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:429)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(JobManager.scala:425)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(JobManager.scala:425)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:401)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

---

Comment: Is the file the exception is referring to, on a local file system or a distributed file system? If on a distributed system, can all the nodes access that path? (Assuming it is already not on HDFS)